# For full encryption, does my initial request need to be HTTPS or is it enough for the server to redirect HTTP to HTTPS?

Tags: redirect, encryption, https

We develop a desktop application and it makes requests to our own API endpoints. Right now all the requests that the desktop application makes to our API are HTTP. I now want all those requests from within the application to be encrypted. Is it enough to simply do an .htaccess HTTP to HTTPS redirect to achieve that? Or do I need to go into the app and make sure that each request starts out as HTTPS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really need to make sure that each API request is done via HTTPS in the first place.

A re-direct (if it even works with POST requests at all) would just result in the request being sent twice (and the first one would be unencrypted, so that an eavesdropper could read everything).

Also, if you app does not require HTTPS (potentially with a pinned server certificate) it is subject to man-in-the-middle attacks: The man in the middle can just intercept the request, never connect you to HTTPS, change the response data at will and your app would not mind.

Comment: In your last paragraph, what do you mean by "require HTTPS"? Are you talking about a different issue than my original question? Do you mean when the app gets the response?

Comment: The app should insist on having HTTPS (with proper certificate, minimum key strength and everything) when it connects to your server. If anything fishy goes on (such as your server redirecting back to HTTP), it should abort communication. It should not rely on having the server manage upgrading to HTTPS by means of redirect (even if that was completely secure), it should enforce it itself.

Comment: A good example of this principle is modern browsers refusing to connect to servers that support certain outdated ciphers, even if their own connection would be using a modern cipher, because other people might use the old cipher to hack into the server (and thus into their own connection).

Comment: I don't understand. Within the desktop app, you are saying that I need to change every request to HTTPS. I will do that. But does anything additional need to be done?